# Transactional Email Templates Missing after Upgrade from 1.7 to 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

I've recently upgraded my magento 1.7.0.2 to 1.9.2.0. Everything works fine, except when I go to system>transactional emails, I don't see any of my previously created templates. Also, when I click 'Add New Template', the load default template dropdown is empty and even the page is not loaded completely. Please suggest what went wrong here.

[image: Add new template for transactional email not loading]

Comment: Did you check your php/magento error logs?

Comment: Any solution about that problem ?

Answer (score 0):

This has not happened on a site I have upgraded through the versions.

However, the mail template processing code is different in 1.9 and there are new 'mobile friendly' templates.

My recommendation is to use the new 1.9 templates and to customise them to how your last templates were. This should be a good use of your time, resurrecting the old templates would probably take longer and not result in the 'mobile friendly' bonus that you have with the 1.9 files.